Relativistic time effects or gravitational lensing in solar observations made by observatories and satellites?
As mentioned, I was wondering about whether there are any phenomena affecting the measurement made in Earths time-scale after a physics seminar at IISERTVM. Any discussions and answers from specific researchers?

Within the Solar System, those effects are usually pretty tiny, and hence negligible. But see The JPL Planetary and Lunar Ephemerides DE440 and DE441, Ryan S. Park et al 2021 AJ 161 105. A section in that paper outlines the procedure required to convert times at various Solar System locations to a common time scale.

cool. ty for your time.

No worries. When using the JPL ephemeris, you can get "raw" geometric data, data corrected for light-time delay, or data corrected for light-time and stellar aberration. "Relativity is included in observables via 2nd order terms in stellar aberration and the deflection of light due to gravity fields of the Sun (and Earth, for topocentric observers)". See https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/ & https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/tutorials.html
